# A handle to temporary unique_ptr returned by function

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, move, unique-ptr

I've tried to read some posts regarding ownership of objects, and how some exceptions apply when copy-constructing a unique_ptr which essentially is forbidden. Of course I pass AND return it by reference, so no copying has to be involved.

```
std::unique_ptr<T>& ptr_func(std::unique_ptr<T>& p) {
    return p;
}
```

Passing an instance of a pointer to this function, is no problem. It basically goes into the function and comes out unchanged, regardless what it points to.

Now comes my question: Imagine my pointer of interest is pointing to an object containing several attributes, and I can only retrieve this pointer in form of a function's return value, E.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<T>& ptr_func() //say this function returns my pointer.
```

Now, let's say it takes quite some computation to retrieve this pointer (e.g. by iterating through a large vector), and I want to set/get many different attributes of the object it points to. Then it becomes very impractical not to be able to have a second (temporary) handle to the pointer or object it is pointing to, as I have to call the function that returns the pointer, for every single action. The compiler DOES somehow create a second reference in one known case: Let's say I pass the function returning my pointer as argument to another function, that changes attributes of the object being pointed to:

```
void set_attributes(std::unique_ptr ptr) {
    ptr->change_something();
    ptr->change_something_else();
}
```

Like so:

```
void set_attributes(function_returning_pointer())
```

In this case, the **function_returning_pointer()** is only called once, regardless how many times its return value is used in the body of **set_attributes()**
How does this work?

Comment: _"Passing an instance of a pointer to this function, is no problem. It basically goes into the function and comes out unchanged, regardless what it points to."_ Then, I don't see any reason why not work with an ordinary pointer here. Smart pointers are for managing ownership and should not be overused this way.

Comment: are you sure you really want to pass around the `unique_ptr`? when you just need a modifyable reference to the object pointed to, then pass it this way. where are you getting your pointer from in `function_returning_pointer`? and how does your set_attributes signature really look like? its missing its template parameter and maybe even the reference qualifier?

Comment: If it "*goes into the function and comes out unchanged*", why are you not passing a reference to *`const`* smart-pointer?  I.e. `std::unique_ptr<T>& ptr_func(std::unique_ptr<T> const& p)`.  Only pass a mutable reference if you want to allow the function to *change where `p` points to*.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique_ptr<T>& ptr_func()` is strange signature: you might take ownership... or not.

You probably want clearer functions:

```
T& get_ref();
T* get_ptr();
std::unique_ptr<T> take();
```

From your usage, `set_attributes` should be:

```
void set_attributes(MyObject& ptr) {
    ptr.change_something();
    ptr.change_something_else();
}
```

with usages similar to

```
assert(function_returning_pointer() != nullptr);
set_attributes(*function_returning_pointer());

assert(get_ptr() != nullptr);
set_attributes(*get_ptr());

set_attributes(get_ref());

auto ptr = take();
assert(ptr != nullptr);
set_attributes(*ptr); // set_attributes(*take()) would be useless as object would be destroyed.
```

If really you want to keep passing `unique_ptr` without transfer ownership, your method would be:

```
void set_attributes(std::unique_ptr<MyObject>& ptr) { // prefer MyObject& or MyObject* instead
    assert(ptr != nullptr);
    ptr->change_something();
    ptr->change_something_else();
}
```